# How can I uninstall Ubuntu when installed through Windows 7?

Tags: wubi, 64-bit, uninstall, delete

I installed Ubuntu without doing a partition, I ran the .exe from my Windows 7 OS. For the past week i've been trying to uninstall Ubuntu unsuccesfully.

I went to the Windows 7 control panel to uninstall Ubuntu and the file was deleted from my C drive and there is no Ubuntu partition under the disk management, however when I boot up Ubuntu is still running and works perfectly.

I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the Wubi again im sure they give an option to uninstall from the main menu

Answer (score 2):

Since you installed using Wubi, there is no partition created.

All you need to do is uninstall like you would with any other Windows program.

In Control panel choose, **uninstall a program**. Find Ubuntu in the list and click uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does a few things. It installs a small 'shim' bootloader that the windows bootloader loads, and installs ubuntu into a pair of image files. Assuming you uninstalled wubi, you can do this the ugly way.

While bcdedit will probably do the job, I favour [visualbcd](http://www.boyans.net/DownloadVisualBCD.html) or [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to remove wubi from the bootloader, then delete wubildr.mbr and wubildr (it might be called gldr.mbr and gldr). This should delete the bootloader entry and the bootloaders themselves

There will also be image files - C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk and any other files there can be deleted. This will naturally both free up space, and nuke your old wubi install

Instructions based off the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Answer (score 0):

Wubi will delete the previous install before starting to install the new instance. Once deleted cancel the new installation.

I did three re-installs getting this install to work so well, and it deleted the original one each time. And it cleared the boot menu out of the system partition too.